# How to access font size of text inside of text frame in pptx file by using python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

> Here is my code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

    pptx_file = 'education.pptx'
    presentation = Presentation(pptx_file)

    for slide_number, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
        # Iterate through each shape in the slide
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                # Iterate through each paragraph in the text frame
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    # Iterate through each run in the paragraph
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        font_size = run.font.size
                        # font_size is in Pt, convert to a human-readable format if necessary
                        font_size_pt = font_size.pt if font_size else 'Default size'
                        print(f"Slide {slide_number + 1}, Text: {run.text}, Font size: {font_size_pt}")
```

> I am trying to access font size of text inside of text frame in my pptx file by using python-pptx. Hovewer is keeping to repeate 'Default size'.

I tried did my best to get access font size of text frame. I have read documentation, but could find any valid answer for my question. I hope, anyone can help.

Comment: In [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.font) the font size is accessed though `TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size`. [Here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#textframe-objects) it says that "None indicates the font size should be inherited from its style hierarchy, such as a placeholder or document defaults "

Answer (score 0):

In my (md2pptx) project I have the line:

```
if font.size < Pt(24):
```

which works for me.

It needs:

```
from pptx.util import Pt
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Hope you are having a nice day. thank you for your help, but it did not work. I am not being able to access font size of my text frame, it is just repeading NONE value.

I am using font_size.pt to access it, it is just returning None.

I only cound access my font size value by converting my pptx file into pdf. However, it is taking so much time.

Comment: Ah, I see you're not extracting the `run` objects from the paragraphs. You should do.

Comment: I tried it Mr, but still not working.

Comment: Show us the code now you've added run objects, please.

Comment: `for slide_number, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    font_size = run.font.size
                    font_size_pt = font_size.pt if font_size else 'Default size'
                    print(f"Slide {slide_number + 1}, Text: {run.text}, Font size: {font_size_pt}")
                    if font_size and font_size < Pt(24):
                        pass`

Comment: Mr, I need to turn my pptx file into json data. Everything is working perfect, but when it comes to font size, I am not being able to access font size of each text frame.

Comment: I just need to get font size of existing text on pptx file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to accessing the font size at the run level, where it might not be explicitly set. Try accessing the font size at the paragraph level.

```
from pptx import Presentation

pptx_file = 'education.pptx'
presentation = Presentation(pptx_file)

for slide_number, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
    # Iterate through each shape in the slide
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            # Iterate through each paragraph in the text frame
            for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                font_size = paragraph.style.font.size
                # font_size is in Pt, convert to a human-readable format if necessary
                font_size_pt = font_size.pt if font_size else 'Default size'
                print(f"Slide {slide_number + 1}, Text: {paragraph.text}, Font size: {font_size_pt}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it did not work. It is still returning 'Default size'. 
Did it work with your file ?